# Symbolic relationship between Mothers and Exiles

Tags: midrash, drush, golus-exile, imahot-matriarch-mothers, four-cups-wine

I am interested in what is the correspondence between the Four Mothers (Sarah, Rivkah, Rachel and Leah) and the Four Exiles (Babylonian, Persian/Medean, Greek and Roman).

There is a lot of indirect evidence that such a relationship exists. Particularly, by the Seder, I've often heard quoted in the name of the Maharal that the 4 cups represent the 4 mothers, in order of being drunk (i.e. Kiddush, Maggid, Birchas HaMazon, Hallel correspond to the above list of Mothers in the same order), and the same 4 cups represent the 4 exiles, but I never saw what is the relationship between these.

Could someone please explain it to me. Thank you very much.

Comment: http://www.breslev.co.il/articles/%D7%97%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%97/%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A2_%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%AA__%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A2_%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%94%D7%95%D7%AA.aspx?id=21794&language=english

Comment: @GershonGold Same one in English - http://www.breslev.co.il/articles/holidays_and_fast_days/pesach/four_cups__four_mothers.aspx?id=21697&language=english

Comment: @GershonGold I suppose this is one half of the answer - the other is to link the cups to the exiles. But I'm surprised no one posted the Maharal...